# Artin 4.5.11 bijection between $SO_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ and unit circle

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, orthogonal-matrices

This is question 4.5.11 in Artin's Algebra, first edition.

> Let $v$ be a vector of unit length, and let $P$ be the plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ orthogonal to $v$. Describe a bijective correspondence between points on the unit circle in $P$ and matrices $\mathit{P} \in SO_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ [I find $\mathit{P}$ a weird choice of name of matrix, I will use $\mathbf{P}$ instead] whose first column is $v$

I know the following: If $v$ has unit length and is orthogonal to $P$, then $\mathbf{P}\mathbf{P}^{T}=I$. Likewise, because $P$ is the unit circle, we can think of any point in $P$ as a rotation in the plane orthogonal to $v$. So that, if we focus only on that plane, we get a matrix $\mathbf{P}' \in SO_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ with the usual properties such as $\mathbf{P}'(\mathbf{P}')^{T}=I_{2}$. I made a figure of my geometric understanding of the question:

[image: v and Orthogonal unit circle]

The grey disc is the unit circle orthogonal to $v$.

Is my understanding correct? How can we construct such bijection?

Comment: If $\mathbf P$ is an orthogonal matrix, the it's product with it's transpose is the identity matrix.

Comment: @EthanDlugie I agree. I think I could have written that part better, what I was trying to write is that the first row and the first column of $\mathbf{P}\mathbf{P}^{T}$ will have a $1$ on the diagonal and $0$ elsewhere. If we consider the whole matrix, then yes, we get the identity.

Comment: I like your figure a lot! If you think of this set of matrices in $SO_3(\Bbb R)$ as "the set of right-handed orthonormal (ordered) bases for $\Bbb R^3$ where the first vector is $v$", does that give you any ideas about what the bijection might be?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks! I wanted to try Inkscape for a long time, it took me the whole morning hahahah my PhD supervisor wouldn't be happy about it. Coming back to your question. I think the bijection is taking the second and third columns of $\mathbf{P} \in SO_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ to be the coordinates of any point on the unit circle in $P$. But is suppose this is not formal enough?

Comment: note: the problem is for point *on* the unit circle not *in* it.  My hint is select arbitrary matrix $P_0$ in you subset of $SO_3$ and consider what happens when you left multiply said subset by $P_0^T$

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks for the hint and the correction. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by the subset of $SO_{3}$? Do you mean the subset so that the first column is $v$?

Comment: Yes that's the one.  It would have been helpful to have a name for this subset (say $S$ or $S_v$) but Artin doesn't supply one I guess.

Comment: Taking the second and third column as *coordinates* isn't quite right.. In fact, just the second column by itself is a unit vector that is perpendicular to $v$, so lies on this unit circle. It might seem a bit weird to totally ignore the third column, but in fact the third column is completely determined by the first two, given that the matrix is special orthogonal. You could just as well pick the third one instead and that would just rotate your bijection by $90^\circ$.

Comment: @user8675309 Because $S$ is a subset of $SO_{3}$, we would have that $P^{T}_{0}w$ for $w \in S$ is a rotation along the orthogonal plane of $v$. I believe (correct me if I am wrong) this is related to what I wrote after the question statement. Let me write it again in other words: because $v$ has unit length, then the resulting matrix will look like this:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a & b\\
0 & c & d
\end{pmatrix}
but $SO_{3}$ is a group, so the product of any of its elements is in $SO_{3}$ so $P_{0}^{T}w$ has a defined structure.

Comment: you can say a lot more about a, b, c, d....

Comment: @user8675309 yep, because this product is in $SO_{3}$ we also know:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a & b\\
0 & -b & a
\end{pmatrix}, and that $a^{2}+b^{2}=1$.

Comment: in other words $\begin{pmatrix}  a & b\\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}\in SO_2$ which is equivalent to exactly one point on the unit circle.  So $P_0^T: S\longrightarrow \text{co-domain}\cong S^1 \text{ (unit circle)}$.  $P_0^T$ is injective by design.  You just need to show that everything in the co-domain has a pre-image in $S$ (i.e. surjectivity).

Comment: @user8675309, I agree that's a nice algebraic way to biject with the unit circle in $\Bbb R^2$. However since the question specifically asks about the unit circle *in the plane perpendicular to $v$*, I have to imagine the intended solution is $\mathbf P \mapsto \mathbf P \mathbf e_2$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen it's true.  That said there is an (obvious?) bijection between the matrix having columns 2 and 3 of some $\mathbf P\in S$ i.e. $\mathbf P \begin{pmatrix} 0 &0\\ 1& 0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$  and just its second column, i.e. $\mathbf P\mathbf e_2$ so is just a minor tweak at the end.  The fact that after multiplication by $P_0^T$ we get $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & a & b\\ 0 & -b & a \end{pmatrix}$ (isomorphic to $SO_2$ element) mirrors development by Artin on page 124 and seemed worth tying in.

Comment: Hint: Use the cross-product of the 2nd and 3rd column of $P$ to recover the 1st column. Now, map vectors in the circle to the 2nd column.